# TextView and EditText alignment issues

Tags: android, alignment, android-edittext, textview

I'm adding `TextViews` and `EditTexts` to the the UI, but they are overlapping each other. I want them to appear next to each other. What I am missing in this code?

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
            RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
            ll.setId(99);
            sv.addView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 /*Changed the actual value for better Understanding*/; i++) {
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("" + (productStr[i]));
            tv.setId(i);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            ll.addView(tv, lay);
            et = new EditText(this);
            et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            et.setEms(2);
            allEds.add(et);
            et.setId(i);

             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv.getId());
            ll.addView(et, p);


        }
        this.setContentView(sv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add extra layouts, you could do it with the `RelativeLayout`. The code below should layout the `TextView` and `EditText` like you want:

```
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ll.setId(99);
        ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

        sv.addView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("" + (productStr[i]));
            tv.setId(1000 + i);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            if (i != 0) {
                lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 2000 + i - 1);
            }
            ll.addView(tv, lay);
            et = new EditText(this);
            et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            et.setEms(2);
            et.setId(2000 + i);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
            if (i != 0) {
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 2000 + i - 1);
            }
            ll.addView(et, p);
        }
        this.setContentView(sv);
```

Comment: Thanks Luksprog. I tried the solution but its causing my apps force close:-((

Comment: @user1531689 My code works as I tested it so the error must come from another part of your code. Can you post somewhere(like http://pastebin.com/ ) the exception you get from the logcat?

Comment: @ Luksprog, i have paste the exception in pestbin as u asked me to do.

Comment: @user1531689 Well you have to give me the link to see it.

Comment: @ Luksprog thanks dude.. my app is working fine now.. There was error in my code what i just got and removed.. Thanks a Lot:-))

Comment: @user1531689 If my answer helped you could accept it by clicking on the check mark near my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, and leave positioning to the layouter.

PS: it's spelled "them" not "dem".

Comment: smart guy(WebnetMobile.com)... dude i'll definitely appreciate you if you answer what i exactly want.... hope you know around 150 characters are there for the title where you have to manage with the heading.

Comment: Sorry WebnetMobile.com.. was bit rude last time. was little tensed. will try to not use chat language again:-))

Comment: No problem. Frankly, if I'd know about 150 chars limit I'd probably not comment on 'dem' at all. So we're square :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LinearLayout` in your xml. Something like this will generate a `TextView` next to the `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S: There are few norms which everyone follows in asking questions on this forums, like not using chat language in your question. Make short and sweet title and you can write any amount of explanation in your post.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 tv.setText("" + (productStr[i]));
  
 et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 allEds.add(et);
   

}


Hi Abhilasha...

I Tried above with the xml you had suggested and it works like a charm but getting only one TextView and EditText on screen and that too the last one of the loop.

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 tv.setText("" + (productStr[i]));
  
 et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 allEds.add(et);
   

}


Hi Abhilasha...

I Tried above with the xml you had suggested and its working fine but getting only one TextView and EditText on screen and that too the last one of the loop.

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: how many `TextView`s and `EditText`s do you need? You have to define those many of them in your Layout.xml file. I have edited my answer  for the case where you need two rows of `TextView` and `EditText`

Comment: Number of text boxes and EditTexts are not limit in my projrct as it coulkd be 10 or 20 depends upon the requirement. Anyways i have solved that Issue and its working fine..Thanks Abhilasha for your concern.. Thanks a lot..:-))